# Get last modified date of latest file in a storage account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Scenario:program that can look at storage account and process all new & modified files and take an action if there is any new ones. For that i want to find the last modified date of the latest file .How can i achieve this?Anyone please help me.

```
namespace ListStorageAccntFiles
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Console.Clear();

        CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        var BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("samples‐workitems");

       //Code to list the blobnames in Console
       var list = Container.ListBlobs();
       List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b =>b.Name).ToList();

       blobNames.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
       //Code for the remaining

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use blockBlob.Properties.LastModifiedUtc  to get the last modified details of a blob in azure

Comment: Thanks @vivekkv . It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer(simply last modified date of all files,not the specific latest file).

```
//Code to get the last modified date

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
var lastModifiedDate = blockBlob.Properties.LastModified;
Console.WriteLine(lastModifiedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

As vivek mentioned, we can use LastModifyedUtc to get the lastest modified file. We can also use webjob blob trigger to monitor the latest change, please have a look at my reply in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122699/store-a-liststring-to-sql-database-table).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
CloudFile file = yourDirectory.GetFileReference(fileName);
file.FetchAttributes();
DateTime lastWriteDate = DateTime.Parse(file.Properties.LastModified.ToString());
```